# Special characters slash(/) passed as parameter in url and corrupt css?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Add last special character slash(/) in website `url` and corrupt `css`.

```
url Ex.www.demo.com/Default.aspx
```

My problem is `www.demo.com/Default.aspx/` adds slash(/) and corrupts css.

How can I fix it?

Comment: So you want to remove the ending slash after Default.aspx ?

Comment: no remove i have required slash.

Comment: So you need it and its already removed from there and you want to put it again ?

Comment: it problem only aspx page not in html and any other page.

Comment: I am not able to understand what are you exactly trying to do here. Do you want to remove that slash or add it or what else ?

Comment: i have add slash because i am using querystring and querysting add slash.

Comment: Can you show some more code and explain from where slash is coming and what do you want to do with it ?